# How I can make Javassist work with Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, javassist

I want to perform bytecode instrumentation on servelets using Javassist, but the challenge is that, whatever instrumentation I did, it is not reflected in Tomcat classes. I could clearly see that this is an issue with class loaders but I couldn't make it even work with custom class loaders. I tried searching for any  examples on this but couldn't find any. Do you have any examples on how we can make Tomcat work with Javassist?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting your agent to tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using `ClassPool.getDefault()` in order to run your example on Tomcat. This will  not work as application servers do not run on the class path.

In order to inform Javassist of the classes of a specific application, you need to append the classes of the current class loader. You can do this by appending an instance of `LoaderClassPath` to the current class pool which references your application's class loader.

Comment: Hi Rafael, below is what I am doing, is this correct way of loading classpool?     ClassPool parent = ClassPool.getDefault();
                ClassPool cp = new ClassPool(parent);
                cp.insertClassPath(new ClassClassPath(this.getClass()));
                ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                cp.insertClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(cl));